# paster errors after installing distribute 0.6.10

Tags: python, plone, paster, distribute

Been working on a Plone site for the last few weeks, it's the first time I've worked on one using buildout for recipes and paster for template generation, and it's been a learning curve.

two days ago, everything was working fine.

Yesterday, I started working from my  known good source and used paster to generate boilerplate for a new archetype, worked fine.  I edited the buildout (as I've done several times before) to account for the new item, ran buildout, and got a hung build (kept repeating that it was generating distribute)

Googling indicated that this was due to a version mismatch, and that I should upgrade to the latest version of distribute, so I did so (to 0.6.10)

Now, that error is gone, but so is any ability to do paster.  Even running
 `paster create --list-templates`
kicks out the error:

```
F:\Plone\src>paster create --list-templates
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Plone\Python\Scripts\paster-script.py", line 5, in ?
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Hope someone can help, b/c I'm pretty stalled right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the problem had to do with the new version of distribute apparently doesn't squash the old version correctly.  I had to manually rename the old egg, delete teh new one, then re-install the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You're spot on to delete the distribute egg and reinstall.

If your easy_install produces a similar issue (mine did after deleting my setuptools egg) you can manually reinstall distribute with:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python distribute_setup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

[New distribute release: use new zc.buildout to prevent recursion](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2009/12/12/new-buildout-and-distribute-without-recursion.html)

I don't know that much about that particular part of the stack, but might be related?

Comment: yes, that's the exact article that led me to upgrade to distribute 0.6.10.  After doing so is when my paster problem started